# sqlite3 performance testing - how to quickly reset/clear the cache

Tags: sqlite, query-optimization

I hope this is a simple question.

When doing query performance testing, running an identical, consecutive query will always return a response faster than the first attempt (generally, significantly faster).

What's the easiest/fastest method to 'reset' sqlite3 back to its default state?

Running `VACUUM` can take quite awhile and is obviously doing more than simply 'resetting' things.

Thank you,

Comment: This question is actually about the OS file cache.

Comment: Well...if you've got root you can wipe the entire cache for the OS, but that's a bit...heavy handed.

Answer (score 1):

So, it seems as though sqlite3 doesn't have the ability to do this on its own. You can compensate for this by flushing the pagecache/inodes in linux by running the following as root:

```
echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

For it to be effective for performance testing, you'll need to run this command between each iteration. The value won't change (which is counter intuitive), but each time the value is written to the file, the flush process is activated.